# when 1 record only php loop json are not looped

Tags: php, json

```
    <?php
    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");

    $json = json_decode($data); 

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "12345") or die("Could not connect");
    mysql_select_db("db_shuttlebus") or die("Could not select database");

    foreach($json as $obj){
   echo $obj->_id;
    }
    ?>
```

firebug json string

this is only 1 record json string
`{"_id":2,"Route_Seq":2,"Location_Name":"ABC","Route_LocationID":6,"Route_ID":"1","id":null}`

this is 2 records, and work fine

`[{"_id":2,"Route_Seq":1,"Location_Name":"perak","Route_LocationID":"6","Route_ID":"1","id":null},{"_id":1,"Route_Seq":2,"Location_Name":"TRY","Route_LocationID":"1","Route_ID":"1","id":null}]`

**Update : when json only 1 record, then it wont be loop,

 if more than 1 record then it is working fine, why?**

Comment: Not clear what you're asking here - please explain.

Comment: @AlexWalker updated, please review

Comment: Give an example data set and what you expect to happen for each.

Comment: @Tim just print the _id

Comment: my question is just simple and clear, i dont understand why down my vote

Comment: We have no idea what your json data looks like. There is no way for us to tell what it is going to do without guessing.

Comment: just a simple english, if JSon only are having 1 record then it is unable to echo the `_id`, whenever more than 1 record in JsOn , then i get the echo _id. that is all.Simple and clear, how come no body understand...

Comment: Just post a JSON string. How hard is that? Is it an array or an object, or maybe a #$@@$# string. I have no idea I can't read your mind.

Comment: There is nothing for foreach to iterate over in your example data. `$data` is a single instance of stdClass

Comment: @tim how about json are having 2 records? so i have to determine is 1 record only read the single instance, if more than 1 then using loop, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: return a JSON array both times. `foreach` iterates over arrays and you are not giving it one. There is nothing wrong with an array containing one element.

Your JSON for one record should look like this:

```
 [{"_id":2,"Route_Seq":2,"Location_Name":"ABC","Route_LocationID":6,"Route_ID":"1","id":null}]
```

If you can't change the form of the data that is coming back then use the function `is_array` to test it before looping, and handle one record as a special case.

Specifically, you can replace the loop at the bottom with something like this:

```
 if(is_array($json)) {
      foreach($json as $obj){
           echo $obj->_id;
      }
 } else {
      echo $json->_id;
 }
```